# Save a json/csv file (fetched from an API) to a spreadsheet document without using a loop - Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script

I can fetch the data using two different urls depending whether I want to file to be csv or json.

1. **CSV edition**

In the case of the csv url I do the following:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data")

get_url="https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.csv? 
    datum_tenaamstelling=20200404%20&$limit=20000";

  var result_data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(get_url);
  var raw_data = result_data.getContentText()
  Logger.log(raw_data);
```

I end up with a string that I can not store it to the spreadsheet file without using a loop.

2. **JSON edition**

Using the json url, I am doing the following:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data")

get_url="https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json? 
datum_tenaamstelling=20200404%20&$limit=20000";

var result_data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(get_url, options);
var raw_data = result_data.getContentText()
var json_list = JSON.parse(raw_data)

 for(var i = 0; i < json_list.length; i++) {
    var obj = json_list[i];

    Logger.log(obj.merk);
    
    sheet.appendRow([obj.kenteken, 
                     obj.merk, 
                     obj.catalogusprijs, 
                     obj.datum_eerste_afgifte_nederland,
                     obj.datum_eerste_toelating,
                     obj.datum_tenaamstelling
                    ]);
}
```

Which again I end up using an iteration which is not practical if I want to store 20000 rows to the spreadsheet. After sometime it stops and returns a runtime error.

Is there any way I can directly copy the data to the spreadsheet file?
For example to do something like that:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 1,raw_data.length,raw_data[0].length).setValues(raw_data);
```

Comment: I do not know what your data looks like, but if it is a 2-D array with the format `Object[][]` like a value range, I don't see any reason why you cannot do `sheet.getRange(1, 1,json_list.length,json_list[0].length).setValues(json_list);`

Comment: @zig url is there to check, if you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to store specific from a JSON object response

- Looping through all data and call the method `sheet.appendRow()` during each iteration would indeed be slow and inefficient due to the number of calls - see [Apps Script Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#minimize_calls_to_other_services).
- A significantly more efficient way to do it, would be to create an array to store the data of interest before writing it a single time with `setValues()`.
- The sample below still incorporates a `for` loop, however given that no calls to external services are made during each iteration, the whole script took only around 10 s to execute and write 12582 rows of data into the sheet.

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("data")  
  get_url="https://opendata.rdw.nl/resource/m9d7-ebf2.json?datum_tenaamstelling=20200404%20&$limit=20000"; 
  var result_data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(get_url);
  var raw_data = result_data.getContentText()
  var json_list = JSON.parse(raw_data)
  var array = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < json_list.length; i++) {
    var obj = json_list[i];
    array.push([obj.kenteken, 
                obj.merk, 
                obj.catalogusprijs, 
                obj.datum_eerste_afgifte_nederland,
                obj.datum_eerste_toelating,
                obj.datum_tenaamstelling
               ]);
  }
  sheet.getRange(1, 1,array.length,array[0].length).setValues(array);
}
```